# Why I cannot use a decltype in range-for with multi-dimension arrays?

Tags: c++11, for-loop, multidimensional-array, decltype

I have a problem here. I am trying to use `decltype` in `range-for` loop for using multi-dimension array:

```
    int a[][4]{
    {0, 1, 2, 3 },
    {4, 5, 6, 7 },
    {8, 9, 10, 11}
};

for (auto& row : a) { // reference is needed here to prevent array decay to pointer
    cout << "{";
    for (auto col : row)
        cout << col << ", ";
    cout << "}" << endl;
}


decltype (*a) row{ *a};
cout << sizeof(row) << endl;
cout << typeid(row).name() << endl;

//  for (decltype(*a) row : *a) {
//      for (int col : row)
//          cout << col << ", ";
//      cout << endl;
//  }
```

With `auto` I can easily iterate over the the array But with `decltype` it doesn't work for me.

What I get above if I uncomment the code is: `cannot convert from int to int(&)[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the line `for(decltype(*a) row : *a)` is incorrect. Try to read it correctly: for each array of 4 int from a, not from *a.

The code may look like:

```
for (decltype(*a) row : a) {
    for (int col : row)
        cout << col << ", ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

- Dereferencing a (*a) with `decltype` will yield an array of 4 integers. So the type is `int[4]`. Unlike using keyword `auto` where it yields `int*`.